# SQL select id where other columns are identical

Tags: sql, relational-database, sap-ase

If I have a table of properties with columns owner, wallColor and roofColor (let's say one owner can own multiple houses but houses can have only one owner), how can I select all owners who only have houses that have identical wall and roof colors?

So if I had

```
owner   wallColor  roofColor
Bob     Red        Green
Bob     Blue       Blue
Greg    Yellow     Yellow
Greg    Black      Black
```

it should only return Greg, because Bob has a house with red walls and a green roof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t1.owner
 FROM tablename t1
 WHERE t1.owner NOT IN
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT t2.owner FROM tablename t2
    WHERE t2.wallColor != t2.roofColor
 )
```

Comment: This whole thing is actually selecting from a query, I guess I should point that out.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT owner 
FROM ytable 
WHERE owner NOT IN 
(
    SELECT owner 
    FROM ytable 
    WHERE wallColor <> roofColor
)
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DISTINCT OWNER FROM ... WHERE wallcolor = roofcolor
EXCEPT
SELECT [DISTINCT] OWNER FROM ... WHERE wallcolor <> roofcolor;

:-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM table WHERE wallColor=roofColor AND 
owner NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM table WHERE wallColor<>roofColor )
```

That would be my approach, but it may need some tweaking.

Comment: Bob has a house where wallcolor=roofcolor ;)

Comment: you would select Bob, which fails as he has house which has different colours.

Answer (score 0):

Using `exists` operator:

```
select *
from table t
where not exists(
    select 1
    from table t1
    where t1.owner = t.owner and t1.wallColor <> t1.roofColor
)
```